# I am creating mixed application with java and javafx

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I am creating a small application with mixed of java and javafx.. So i have small doubt that is that possible to connect java to javafx page while using a button jFrame in java..

Comment: So you mean you are mixing javafx with swings right?

Comment: yes I am expecting . I newer in Javafx so creating small application by trying to connect with javafx via java swing

Comment: Have a look here : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm

Answer (score 1):

jewelsea pointed out that there is a way to embed javafx components inside Swing using [JFXPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html).
So, **yes**, you can put a javafx [Button](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html) in a [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html), so long as you wrap that Button in a [JFXPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html).

JavaFX also gives you a way to put Swing components inside a JavaFX Application. It's called [SwingNode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html).
So, **yes**, you can put a [JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) in a javafx [Stage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html), so long as you wrap that JButton in a SwingNode.

Comment: JavaFX has had a mechanism to embed JavaFX components inside Swing applications since the initial release of JavaFX 2.0.  The class to do this is [JFXPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html).  The linked javadoc provides a sample of how to use it.

Comment: @jewelsea thank you! I didn't know that, I will update this answer